# Python: how to replace a column value in one dataframe from another without removing duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two data frames: one derived from a csv file and another is a output from a sql db

DataFrame1 looks like this:(derived from csv file) **df1**

```
 |BId    |Timestamp    |SequenceNumber|TypeCode|LineNumber|Qty |Grade      |StartDate    |EndDate      
0|1002899|19/08/19 0:03|1355          |f       |10        |3.55|Aeiouswe   |18/08/19 4:49|20/08/19 1:00
1|1002899|19/08/19 0:04|1356          |f       |10        |8.4 |hdujeujdido|18/08/19 4:49|20/08/19 1:00
3|1002899|19/08/19 0:13|1357          |f       |10        |3.56|hdujeujdido|18/08/19 4:49|20/08/19 1:00
4|1002899|19/08/19 0:26|1358          |f       |10        |12.2|iueoe      |18/08/19 4:49|20/08/19 1:00
6|1001346|19/08/19 0:08|1844          |f       |10        |110 |derets     |18/08/19 4:49|20/08/19 1:00
7|1002867|19/08/19 1:39|1461          |f       |10        |21.8|derets     |18/08/19 4:49|20/08/19 1:00
8|1002867|19/08/19 1:39|1461          |f       |20        |500 |uijsts     |18/08/19 4:49|20/08/19 1:00
```

Second dataframe is derived from sql: **df2**

```
 |BId|SiteId
0|1001346|180
1|1002899|181
2|1002867|182
3|1002375|183
4|1002376|184
5|1002377|185
6|1002378|186
7|1002379|187
8|1002380|188
9|1002381|189
10|1000438|191
11|1000439|192
12|1000365|193
13|1000288|194
14|1000408|195
15|1001895|10006
16|1002870|10008
17|1002348|10009
18|1002358|10012
```

I want to replace the value of column BId in df1 with the value of column SiteId from df2 if the BId between df1 matches df2

My expected output would look like this:

```
 |BId    |Timestamp    |SequenceNumber|TypeCode|LineNumber|Qty |Grade      |StartDate    |EndDate      
0|181|19/08/19 0:03|1355          |f       |10            |3.55|Aeiouswe   |18/08/19 4:49|20/08/19 1:00
1|181|19/08/19 0:04|1356          |f       |10            |8.4 |hdujeujdido|18/08/19 4:49|20/08/19 1:00
3|181|19/08/19 0:13|1357          |f       |10            |3.56|hdujeujdido|18/08/19 4:49|20/08/19 1:00
4|181|19/08/19 0:26|1358          |f       |10            |12.2|iueoe      |18/08/19 4:49|20/08/19 1:00
6|180|19/08/19 0:08|1844          |f       |10            |110 |derets     |18/08/19 4:49|20/08/19 1:00
7|182|19/08/19 1:39|1461          |f       |10            |21.8|derets     |18/08/19 4:49|20/08/19 1:00
8|182|19/08/19 1:39|1461          |f       |20            |500 |uijsts     |18/08/19 4:49|20/08/19 1:00
```

I have tried using the following method:

```
df1['BId'] = df1['BId'].map(df2.set_index('BId')['SiteId'])
```

But i get the following error
Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Considering that I have duplicate values in df1 for BId, how can i get these values replaced without removing the duplicates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure, there would be a simpler way to do this , but I was able to do this by converting the df1 and df2 to a list
Then using for loop to replace the values and then converting the result back into a dataframe as below:

```
df1list = df1.values.tolist()
df2list = df2.values.tolist()

for n, i in enumerate(df1list):
  for j in df2list:
    if i[0] == j[0]:
      df1list[n][0] = j[1]

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df1list , columns=['BId', 'Timestamp', 'SequenceNumber', 'Code', 'LineNumber', 'Qty','Grade', 'StartDate', 'EndDate'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmm not sure if this will work. You could try it with the replace function:
This function needs to know which Col has to be replaced and requires then a list of the new values. 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

You could try:

```
df1.replace({'BId': df2["SiteId"].tolist()})
```

The tolist() should give you just a list of a column back

Comment: I tried this method, it just prints the df1 as it is no changes are done, neither any errors are displayed

Comment: @pybeginner sorry I was tired. I post a new answer, I tried this code myself. I guess you shoud be able to do the same. I was wron. It does not wants a list, the functions requirs a dictonary.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use this way. I got the wanted output. Sorry that I gave bad advice yesterday. Hope it is working now. (I was wrong yesterday, it needs a dictionary and not a list)

```
import pandas as pd

list1 = range(0,100,1)
list2 = range(100,200,1)
list3 = range(200,300,1)
list4 = range(300,400,1)

df1 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": list1,"col2":list1})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"col1": list2,"col2":list2})
print(df1)

dict = df2["col1"].to_dict()
df3 = df1.replace({"col1": dict})
print(df3)
```